# Do I need a own controller for every fmxl file(scene)?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a programm with diffrent scenes, so if have a few fxml files. Does every file need it`s own controller or can I controll all with only one controller?

Comment: Presumably you mean "only one controller *class*". It would be really confusing to do that: you won't know which `@FXML`-injected fields are initialized in which instances of the class. Use a different controller class for each FXML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it is possible to  apply the same controller (class or instance) to more than one FXML-file.

But according to the *single responsibility pattern* you should not do that.